# React Native: How to achieve drop down menu on click of 3 dots in top header?

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8QnK.png)

I tried several approaches to achieve this on my app. My requirement is, create a clickable 3 dots on the screen header and on click of those 3 dots open a sub menu with some items. Further on click of those items a separate screen has to be opened.

But every time i am getting issues. I tried below approach

1. react-native-popup-menu : unable to implement it.

I am stuck with this from several days, any approach / suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [react-native-element-dropdown](https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-element-dropdown)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
  import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

  const data = [
    { label: 'Item 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Item 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
    { label: 'Item 4', value: '4' },
    { label: 'Item 5', value: '5' },
    { label: 'Item 6', value: '6' },
    { label: 'Item 7', value: '7' },
    { label: 'Item 8', value: '8' },
  ];

  const DropdownComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

    const renderLabel = () => {
      if (value || isFocus) {
        return (
          <Text style={[styles.label, isFocus && { color: 'blue' }]}>
            Dropdown label
          </Text>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {renderLabel()}
        <Dropdown
          style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
          placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
          inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
          iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
          data={data}
          search
          maxHeight={300}
          labelField="label"
          valueField="value"
          placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
          searchPlaceholder="Search..."
          value={value}
          onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
          onChange={item => {
            setValue(item.value);
            setIsFocus(false);
          }}
          renderLeftIcon={() => (
            <AntDesign
              style={styles.icon}
              color={isFocus ? 'blue' : 'black'}
              name="Safety"
              size={20}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  export default DropdownComponent;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      padding: 16,
    },
    dropdown: {
      height: 50,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      borderWidth: 0.5,
      borderRadius: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
    },
    icon: {
      marginRight: 5,
    },
    label: {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      left: 22,
      top: 8,
      zIndex: 999,
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    placeholderStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    selectedTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    iconStyle: {
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
    },
    inputSearchStyle: {
      height: 40,
      fontSize: 16,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a modal. Design it according to your need and open it on click. Inside of modal you can simply make an array of the actions you are going to perform like:

```
const actions=[
"Date range",
"Specific Merchant",
"Repayment History",
]
```

Then use actions.map to map these to the your design.
After it, for performing the action on press of any element, you can get the index of clicked element and perform specific action.